# I am trying to design a shiny app in R but my app is unable to pick variable names from the data. I am attaching the code below

Tags: r, shiny

In the following code, I am trying to create a shiny app that has fluid page layout. In Sidebar layout, I want to give option to the user to choose the variable using Radio Buttons.

The problem with my code is that it's unable to pick the data from the variables.

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Covid Crisis in Pakistan and India"),
    sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(radioButtons("variable","Choose Variable",choices=names(data))),
                  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
                    tabPanel("Graph",plotlyOutput("plot"))
                  )))
  )
  
  
  server <- function(input,output){
    output$plot <- renderPlotly(
      ggplotly(ggplot(data=data, aes(x=date,y=input$variable,color = code))+
                 geom_line()+
                 geom_point(alpha=0.2)+
                 theme_classic())
    )
    
  }

  shinyApp(ui=ui, server= server)
```

I got my output like this!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This question is recurrent. In `input$variable`, you have a character string. You can use `aes_string`:

```
aes_string(x = "date", y = input$variable, color = "code")
```